# Getting only email address to display when using message.getFrom() in JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Currently when using JavaMail if I use `getFrom()` to decompose a message into its separate parts the `getFrom()` will also display the name of the sender. This may be a simple question but how do you make it so only the email address is returned. Sorry if this is a simple question but I cannot seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As it turns out, the address has already been parsed for you.  Because of JavaMail's silly extra layer of abstraction, it's returning [`InternetAddress`](ftp://ftp.cfar.umd.edu/.snapshot/daily.0/pub/sns/javamail-1.4.2/docs/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html) objects as their `Address` superclass.  `Address` objects are pretty much useless.  You need to cast them back down to `InternetAddress` and then just get the email part:

```
Address[] froms = message.getFrom();
String email = froms == null ? null : ((InternetAddress) froms[0]).getAddress();
```