# trim @domain.xxx from email leaving just username

Tags: java

I'm trying to trim the @domain.xxx from email address leaving just the username. I'm not sure how to dynamically select the @ position and everything to the right of it. Could someone please provide an example of how to do this? The trim code below is where I'm lost.

```
email = "example@domain.com"
email....(trim code);
email.replace(email, "");
```

Comment: Can you rely on valid email address?

Comment: there should be sort of `explode()` function which would take `@` as input and return an array of two elements: `example` and `domain.com`.

Comment: @The Sexiest Man in Jamaica That method is called `email.split('@')`

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214372/getting-only-email-address-to-display-when-using-message-getfrom-in-javamail  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To find:
`int index = string.indexOf('@');`

To replace:
`email = email.substring(0, index);`

To summarize:

```
email = "example@domain.com";
int index = email.indexOf('@');
email = email.substring(0,index);
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the explanation too, I now know how to handle things like this dynamically now.

Answer (score 12):

Another approach is to split an email on a nickname and on a domain. Look at [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

There is a code example:

```
String email = "example@domain.com";
String[] parts = email.split('@');

// now parts[0] contains "example"
// and parts[1] contains "domain.com"
```

Comment: I can see where something like this would come in handy, thanks for sharing your example.

Comment: Also you could do: String userName = email.split("@")[0];

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin**

```
email = "example@domain.com"
username = email.takeWhile{ it != '@' }
```

Comment: Or `email.substringBefore("@")`