# indexes Message.getFrom () and its function

Tags: java, android, email, message, javax

I am looking for the indexes of the
Javax. Message.getFrom () and its function

that is to say

GetFrom [0] = return address

GetFrom [1] = .....

And others or something that tells me how to work with the returning array

Regards

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214372/getting-only-email-address-to-display-when-using-message-getfrom-in-javamail

Comment: @Eric - Yes but I need all the items that can be getted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I found a answer.

The headers doesn't come in the same order or qantity.
In facts in one mail, can come more then one Received header, for example.

This is a kind of dificult thing